# What is the last digit of $437^{999999999}$?

Tags: number-theory

I need to find the last digit of

$$437^{999999999} \equiv 7^{999999999} \pmod {10} $$

Where do I go from here? Do I replace $999999999$ with $\phi(10) = 4$
so

$$437^{999999999} \equiv 7^{4} \pmod {10} $$

Then I'm not sure where to go from here? or If I'm even going about this correctly, I've been trying to follow examples with no luck.

Comment: potentially useful link: https://brilliant.org/wiki/finding-the-last-digit-of-a-power/

Comment: Hint: $7^4 = 49^2$.

Comment: there is a theorem that tells you that 7^4 = 1 mod 10. So you can reduce the exponent mod 4.

Comment: You were going fine until near the end ... $7^4 =1 \pmod {10}$ so $7^{999999999}=7^{3} \pmod {10}$ ... 3 :-)

Answer (score 3):

Your last congruence is wrong: from $\varphi(10)=4$, you deduce
$$437^{999999999}\equiv7^{999999999\bmod 4}=7^3=7^2\cdot 7\equiv 9\cdot 7\equiv 3\mod 10.$$

Answer (score 1):

The only things that determine the last digit of $437^x$ are the last digit (i.e., 7) and $x$ itself, so we might as well work with $7^x$ instead of $347^x$. If you repeatedly multiply 7 by itself you can see that the last digit forms a ring: $7^1=7$, $7^2=49$, $7^3=343$, $7^4=2401$, $7^5=16807$ ... so the sequence is four elements long and consists of (7,9,3,1). This means that all we need to do is find what stage in the cycle $7^{999999999}$ is.

If we divide 999999999 by 4 we have a remainder of 3, so the last digit of $347^{999999999}$ is going to be the third element of our cycle (7,9,3,1), which is 3.